# Get row and column name of data.frame according to condition in R

Tags: r

This is probably much easier than I am making it. It is one of those little problems which hangs you up and you wonder why.

Given dataframe as so:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
test.df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

How could one use iterate through the values in each column and return the column name and row name if the value = '1'?

Something like this:

```
for (i in test.df) {
    for (j in i) {
        if (i == 1) {
            print(rowname,columnname)
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Where rowname and columnname are actual values.

Answer (score 12):

Using `which` and `arr.ind=T` is a way:

**Example Data**

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
test.df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

**Solution and Output**

```
#test.df==1 gives a TRUE/FALSE matrix
#which with the arr.ind argument=TRUE gives the row/col of the TRUE elements
a <- which(test.df==1,arr.ind=T)

> a
     row col
[1,]   1   1
```

And then you use the above to get the row and column names:

```
> row.names(test.df[a[,1],] ) #row names
[1] "1"

> names(test.df[a[,2]])       #column names
[1] "a"
```

Comment: I had to use `colnames(test.df[,a[,2]])` to be able to get column names.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread but I am not very satisfied with the previous solutions.

For me the most intuitive is:

```
row.names(data)[which(data$feature1==value)]
```

Which is basically saying: Given the row names of all the data give me those where a given condition is satisfied.

Comment: Simple solution that returns the rownames directly as character vector.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
> col = colnames(test.df)[apply(test.df, 2, function(u) any(u==1))]
> col
[1] "a"
> row = row.names(test.df)[apply(test.df, 1, function(u) any(u==1))]
> row
[1] "1"
```

Comment: No problem, just if you want the row number instead of the row name:
`seq(1, nrow(test.df))[apply(test.df, 1, function(u) any(u==1))]`

Comment: A shorter version can be `row.names(test.df)[test.df == 1]`

Comment: Hey, in this code, instead of checking for u=1, I want to see if any observation in NA and get the column name if the condition is satisfied. Can you suggest where I might be going wrong in this code: `(col = colnames(test.df)[apply(test.df, 2, function(u) any(is.na=T))])`

Comment: you define a function taking an argument "u" and you do not use it in the function...